# Is it possible to Java web service send notification to client from Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, service, apache-axis

Well, past few days I am trying to put plans for my chess server project on the table. It is planned to be made of several web services which interact mutualy. Web services are planned to be made with Java language and deployed onto Apache Tomcat 7.0.20 with Axis2 1.6.0 web service engine.

So far, there will be authentication web service, player pool web service, validation web service and 'bussiness logic' web service which will be only web service known to client application. All clients requests will be done through this service and forwarded respectively.

All players moves must go through web services because of move validation, history and so on. Problem occurs when other player needs to be informed of opponents played move. Persistant client request (to discover is opponent played move) towards service is out of question because player turn change must be immidiate when opponent play his move. How to achive this using java web services and eralier mentioned technologies? Is it possible to web service contacts opposed player and inform him about opponents move? Is there another way to do this with this scope of technologies?

**Edit:** Client application is planned to be desktop application, possibly Java or C#.

Answer (score 2):

One option for Tomcat-to-web-browser push communication is [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (sometimes called *CometD* or *Bayeaux*).

From the wiki article:

> **Comet** is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a web server to ***push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it.***

*(Note: Emphasis Mine)*

What this means is that the server can notify the client of pending changes without the browser specifically polling.  With a good JavaScript framework (such as [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) or [this jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquerycomet/)), you can seamlessly work with older browsers by polling.

Some good links for learning more about Comet:

- [RESTful Web Services and Comet](http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/cometslideshow.html)
- [Comet Slideshow Example on Grizzly](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/07/01/comet-slideshow-example-grizzly)
- [Advanced IO and Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html)
- [Dojo Foundation CometD](http://cometd.org/)

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for response, i'll check into that

Answer (score 0):

You do not state your client technology (browser? desktop app?)

Anyway, there is no direct solution if you are addressing home users. To work with home users, you would need them to open / NAT the needed port to their computer so you can access their PC. It is very complicated to the average home user.

For browser it is even more complicated as they are *clients*, not servers. Maybe some framework might be used to simulate a server inside a browser (I think there is at least one but I cannot recall its name), but that would work like just by repeating ajax calls to the server until a change is made.

And last, if you are checking the server every second, that would be a latency low enough even for "fast-chess".

Comment: Checking server periodicly every second might cause side effects which might be fatal for gameplay. For example if service is under heavy load, response might be delayed overly and player clocks will be out of sync too much.

Comment: Yes, it is a matter that needs fine tuning. But from a broswer it is all you can do (even Comet relies in the browser making continuous requests, even if mitigated by some mechanisms). And a full desktop app as a server raises issues of configuration (NAT / firewall) and is (possibly) an additional security hole in your customer client.